# Error: no such file --> executes the Program

Tags: python, terminal

Every time I try to run a program on my Kali Linux VM, in the terminal, I get ["Error: no such file] and then proceeds to run the program. I have tried changing the code. I have tried running Python 3 instead of Python 2.7.18 and I have debugged... to no avail. I have tried moving the program to another dir but nothing seems to change the result. The steps that I have take are:

1) created the document (.py),

2) wrote my code "print("Hello Word")" to eliminate as much errors as I can on my part,

3) I saved the document,

4) I proceeded to "chmod a+x" the file in terminal to make it execute and finally I tried executing it. These are the steps I made that led me to the error. Thank you so much for the help in advance.

Comment: Can you give a series of shell commands that reproduce your problem?  I suspect you are not adding `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top of your file, or not executing as `python <filename>`

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasn't executing it as python <filename>. I just tried it, and it worked like a charm. I'm still new using Kali and you have saved me so much headache. Thank you again!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you =)